# how to load a large json file (> 40MB) to Solr via cUrl using the command line?

Tags: json, curl, solr, size, limit

### I have many json files of different sizes.  I have no problem loading the json files that are smaller than 40 MB to Solr.  However, the json files that are larger than 40 MB could not be loaded because of the following errors:

### {"error":{"msg":"java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space","trace":"java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.sendError(HttpSolrCall

This is the command I used to load my json files:

curl 'http://localhost:8983/solr/minh/update?commit=true' --data-binary @ABH249_0.json -H 'Content-type:application/json'

I even tried to change the formdataUploadLimitInKB field in the solrconfig.xml to 409800000 but that did not help.

Is there a way to set the limit on how large a json can be loaded into Solr?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can try to play whit XMX memory setting of the JVM. If you are using, the out of the box settings, that could not be enough.
[solr JVM settings](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/JVM+Settings)
You can find detailed description for your own system (OS, comp config, hardware, etc) .